# Get type of object being allocated in operator new

Tags: c++, object, memory-management

Is there a way to get type of object being allocated in operator new?

What I mean is:

```
void* BaseClass::operator new(size_t size)
{
    void* result = ::operator new(size);

    //Get type of object that's being allocated

    return result;
}
```

Comment: Just curious if this is possible

Comment: If you are interested, you should probably overload the operator for the derived classes as well. Right here, it just allocates memory which doesn't have a type yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no mechanism to get this data. `operator new` just allocates raw memory given a size, and only the `new` operator call knows the type to construct the object into the allocated memory.

Answer (score 1):

No, you cannot do this. Operator new is implicitly a static function even if you haven't defined it as so. Since it's a static function, you cannot do stuff like using typeid on the `this` pointer to get the type of the object.