# Overloaded "operator new" wants to see the type it's allocating

Tags: c++11, coding-style, new-operator

This seems like it ought to be obvious, but I'm blanking on it. I have

```
class SimpleMemoryPool {
    char buffer[10000];
    size_t idx;
    void *Alloc(size_t nbytes) { idx += nbytes; return &buffer[idx - nbytes]; }
};

inline void* operator new (size_t size, SimpleMemoryPool& pool)
{
    return pool.Alloc(size);
}

inline void* operator new[] (size_t size, SimpleMemoryPool& pool)
{
    return pool.Alloc(size);
}
```

The idea is that I can allocate new objects out of my `SimpleMemoryPool` and then they'll all be "released" when the `SimpleMemoryPool` is destroyed:

```
void foo()
{
    SimpleMemoryPool pool;
    int *arr = new (pool) int[10];
    double *arr2 = new (pool) double(3.14);
    ...do things with arr and arr2...
    return;  // and arr, arr2 are "released" at this point
}
```

One nitpick I've simplified away: The above code is sketchy because the `double` won't be 8-byte-aligned. Don't worry about that; my real `SimpleMemoryPool` code returns maxaligned chunks.

Here's the next thing you're probably thinking at this point: "Who calls the destructors?!" I.e., if I accidentally write

```
    std::string *arr3 = new (pool) std::string;
```

then I'm in a world of hurt, because the compiler will generate a call to `std::string::string()` for me, but nobody will ever call `std::string::~string()`. Memory leaks, bad stuff follows.

**This is the problem I want to solve.** What I want to do is basically

```
class SimpleMemoryPool {
    ...
    // (std::enable_if omitted for brevity)

    template<typename T, typename... Args>
    T *New(Args... args) {
        static_assert(std::is_trivially_destructible<T>::value, "T must be trivially destructible!");
        void *ptr = this->Alloc(nelem * sizeof (T));
        return new (ptr) T(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
    }

    template<typename ArrayT>
    auto NewArray(size_t nelem) -> std::remove_extent<ArrayT>::type {
        typedef typename std::remove_extent<ArrayT>::type T;
        static_assert(std::is_trivially_destructible<T>::value, "T must be trivially destructible!");
        void *ptr = this->Alloc(nelem * sizeof (T));
        return new (ptr) T[ nelem ];
    }
};

...

    int *arr = pool.NewArray<int>(10);
    double *arr2 = pool.New<double>(3.14);
    std::string *arr3 = pool.New<string>();  // fails the static_assert, hooray!
```

The problem with this approach is that it's ugly. It looks bad, and it invites later maintainers to come along and "fix" the code by adding a "proper" `operator new`, at which point we lose the safety of the `static_assert`.

Is there any way to get the best of both worlds — type-safety via the static_assert, and also a nice syntax?

- You may assume C++11. I also welcome C++14 answers, even though they won't be immediately useful to me.
- Adding a member `operator new` to all my classes (in this example `int` and `double`) is not acceptable. Whatever I do has to work out-of-the-box without changing a million lines of code.
- This is probably a duplicate of [Get type of object being allocated in operator new](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14073661/get-type-of-object-being-allocated-in-operator-new) but I'd still like answers tailored to this particular use-case. There might be some nice idiom of which I'm not aware.

Comment: You probably want to write an allocator rather than overload or replace any operator-new's. Don't use `new`, basically.

Comment: @KerrekSB You mean replace all my `int*` with `std::vector<int,SimpleMemoryAllocator>`? Seems like a good idea in theory but I bet it'd be impractical to convert a whole existing codebase to that style. (Also, even if it sounded practical, I'd have to see an example of how this would work with complicated graphy datatypes, e.g. how I would construct a `struct MyTree { struct MyTree *left, *right; }` in the allocator style without using `operator new`.) Also various other nitpicks about the screweduppedness of C++ allocators, but I know C++14 is going to try to improve matters.

Comment: Fix your `MyTree` to accept an allocator parameter! :-)